# PNG shadows getting pink

Tags: delphi-10.3-rio

A colleague and I are working since many years in Delphi 10.3 and a couple of weeks ago he made a change from TsAlphaImageList to TVirutalImageList as it is automatically managing the PNG sizes.

Since this day, I have on my side an issue with the shadows: my PNGs are pink on both Project and Compiled version. Even more, when my colleague compile it on his side I have no issue, when I compile it in my side I have the pink background therefore I can't even send my executable as it is pink...

Do you have any idea on this trouble? I can't find any topic related to this...
[See the picture bellow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2kmv.png)

Answer (score 0):

I use this components in my projects and got same problem. There is issue with direct loading from TsAlphaImageList into TImageCollection. You can easily bypass this problem.
Open TsAlphaImageList designtime editor, click "Extract all" button and save images in some empty directory. Names of images will be like "[imageIndex].png", so you can open just TImageCollection designtime editor and load them all by selecting all files in directory. Then connect TVirutalImageList with AutoFill-property true and you will get VirutalImageList with same images, order and indexes without pink borders.

Other way - use TsVirtualImageList from AlphaControls, it's manage size of images too. Look at [AlphaControlSite](https://www.alphaskins.com/showdoc.php?l=en&n=12) for more info.